# How to view who owns a file?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, permissions

I know to change an owner you put

```
chown user:group file
```

but what if I want to see who owns a file?

---

The issue I am having is I created a user at `/var/www/new-user` but when he uploads new files to there, they can't be viewed. I think I have to change the owner or group to `www-data`. Not positive.

I already have a user at `/var/www/john` that works fine. I thought I set the new on up the same. I wanted to compare mine and see whats different.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you do `ls -lh file` you will see who owns it and what the permissions are. You could do `ls -lh /var/www/` and compare the results between `/var/www/john` and `/var/www/new-user`.

Answer (score 4):

To see the files ownership try `ls -l`

```
ls -l file
-rw-r--r-- 1 iain users 0 May  5 12:46 file
```

Answer (score 2):

LS is probably the tool you want, but just to provide some additional variety.  You could use

> [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) filename